# Creating a checkbox directive with angular that works for mobile devices

Tags: angularjs

For a project I'm working on at the moment, I need to have styles which aren't supported on regular checkbox elements.

To work around this I've created an angular directive which recreates the checkbox functionality. While this is working for me, I do question that I'm using the correct html markup as something doesn't feel right about what I've got.

Traditionally you'd use something like this for a checkbox with a label:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" /> Click to check
</label>
```

and by clicking on the label it'd toggle the checkbox.

Since I'd like to replicate this functionality with angular, I've knocked up a demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zZth3ch7JallvlPA0bsm) that I believe does the trick but I wonder if I'm missing something? I suppose it's worth mentioning that screen readers are not an issue with this project. I also considered how this may render on mobile devices but since it's only a checkbox it should work correctly.

Have I approached this correctly or am I doing something hideously wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need scope variables you defined in directive.

> {elementId: '@', isChecked:'=?'}

*By the way, what did you want to tell with those '=?' ? Actually it goes 'typeOfVariableConnection'+'attributeName'. So by your way, it should accept two-way binding with attribute named '?'. I don't think such attribute name is allowed by HTML specification.*

**But** you will need value of checkbox outside the my-checkbox directive, so it will be a good idea to pass some scope variable to that directive to have access to it's value in controller.

I've changed plunker a little bit, connected native checkbox and your own by same model value. http://plnkr.co/edit/bJF1uggJjksiRT7Zkj9M?p=preview